# Java Hibernate: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, heroku, heroku-postgres

Sorry 4 my bad English :P

Now I'm testing Hibernate, on MySQL it was OK, but on PostgreSQl I faced with problem (`cause I connected to Heroku DB).
I'm trying to connect to DB, but it throws to me exceptions (I had already checked all properties in hibernate.cfg.xml):

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:postgres://username:password@host:5432/database]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()" because the return value of "ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()" is null
```

There is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgres://username:password@host:5432/database</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

    <mapping class="ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.entity.Brush" />

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil:

```
package ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil {

    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {

                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {

                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }

    }
}
```

Class Brush (mapping):

```
package ua.sillmarry.ArtToolsBot.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "brushes")
public class Brush implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "brushes")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "gd_brush")
    private String gd_brush;

    @Column(name = "gd_img")
    private String gd_img;

    public String toString() {

        return "Brush{\n" +
            "id=" + id + ";\n" +
            "name='" + name + "';\n" +
            "category='" + category + "';\n" +
            "gd_brush='" + gd_brush + "';\n" +
            "gd_image='" + gd_img + "'.";
    }
}
```

Comment: does your postgres has username and password as `username` and `password`??

Comment: no it doesn't, in real code I wrote it correct